# Debugging an implementation of breadth-first search (BFS)

Tags: algorithm, go, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

## Background

I have 3D voxels in 3D space. They are indexed by `x, y, z`. They are labeled `full` or `empty`. I try to efficiently count the number of components consisting of neighbor `full` voxels.

## BFS details

I have the following code that implements the breadth-first search (BFS) algorithm. Each voxel is represented by `[3]int{x, y, z}`.

```golang
// Count separate components consisting of disconnected finite elements.
func (vg *VoxelGrid) CountComponents() int {
    // Map key is (x, y, z) index of voxel.
    visited := make(map[[3]int]bool)
    count := 0
    for z := 0; z < vg.Len.Z; z++ {
        for y := 0; y < vg.Len.Y; y++ {
            for x := 0; x < vg.Len.X; x++ {
                if !visited[[3]int{x, y, z}] {
                    count++
                    vg.bfs(visited, [3]int{x, y, z})
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count
}

// Algorithm: breadth-first search (BFS).
// This is much faster than depth first search (DFS) algorithm.
func (vg *VoxelGrid) bfs(visited map[[3]int]bool, start [3]int) {
    queue := [][3]int{start}
    visited[start] = true

    for len(queue) > 0 {
        v := queue[0]
        queue = queue[1:]

        neighbors := vg.getNeighbors(v)

        for _, n := range neighbors {
            if !visited[n] {
                visited[n] = true
                queue = append(queue, n)
            }
        }
    }
}

// It returns a list of neighbor voxels that are full, i.e. not empty.
func (vg *VoxelGrid) getNeighbors(v [3]int) [][3]int {
    var neighbors [][3]int
    for i := -1; i <= 1; i++ {
        for j := -1; j <= 1; j++ {
            for k := -1; k <= 1; k++ {
                if i == 0 && j == 0 && k == 0 {
                    continue
                }

                x := v[0] + i
                y := v[1] + j
                z := v[2] + k

                if x >= 0 && x < vg.Len.X &&
                    y >= 0 && y < vg.Len.Y &&
                    z >= 0 && z < vg.Len.Z {
                    // Index is valid.
                } else {
                    continue
                }

                // Is neighbor voxel empty or not?
                if vg.IsNotEmpty(x, y, z) {
                    neighbors = append(neighbors, [3]int{x, y, z})
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return neighbors
}
```

## Problem

The implementation above is *not* working correctly. It returns the component count as `1224` for a simple model that should have only `8` components:

[image: Reported component count]

[image: Actual components]

## Question

I stepped through the code by VS Code debugger. But I couldn't figure out the bug. Does anybody see any suspicious thing in the code? Any hint to point me in the right direction?

Comment: "But I couldn't figure out the bug" --- try again: this time ensure that **literally every variable** has the expected value at **every point in time**. As long as you found discrepancy - that's where your bug happens.

Comment: @zerkms Right. I'm trying it now...

Comment: @zerkms The very 1st call to `bfs` function increases the `visited` size by `2041`. But 2nd, 3rd, 4th and any future call to `bfs` function, increases the `visited` size by only `1`. That's a found discrepancy so far.

Comment: Great, what actual value is expected on every call?

Comment: @zerkms A bug is found. It is fixed by this condition: `if vg.IsNotEmpty(x, y, z) && !visited[[3]int{x, y, z}] {}` we have to check if a voxel is empty, before starting to process it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you call `bfs` also on voxels that are `empty`.

In `CountComponents` it is verified that `bfs` is only called on voxels that were not *visited* yet (good):

```
if !visited[[3]int{x, y, z}] {
```

...but it lacks the test whether this voxel is `full` (not good), and `bfs` will happily add it to the queue expecting it is `full`. As a consequence, **every** `empty` voxel is counted as a (1-voxel-sized) component as well.